# Unable to open .csv file in R ,whose file name is obtained by concatenating a string with a variable

Tags: r, string, string-concatenation

```r
airprobread <- function(id) {
  fi <- list()
  for (i in id) {
    if(i < 10) {
      fi[[i]] <- read.csv(file = paste("00",i,".csv",sep=""))
    } else 
    if((i >= 10) & (i < 100)) {
      fi[[i]] <- read.csv(file=paste("0",i,".csv",sep=""))
    } else 
    if (i >= 100) {
      fi[[i]] <- read.csv(file=paste(i,".csv",sep=""))
    }          
  }

  for (j in id) {
    print(fi[[j]]) 
  }
}
```

- I am unable to understand why the concatenation is not happening in the case of `paste()` function
- Files from `001.csv` to `009.csv` and `010.csv` to `099.csv` not opening. Gives comments like:

  > In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file '2.csv': No such file or directory

  > In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file '34.csv': No such file or directory

  but it works for values above `100.csv` (file opens for `315.csv`)

I'm here so pardon me for the formatting.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior locally.

Comment: Think it should be `else if (i >= 100)` instead of just `else ( 1 >= 100)`. After that correction the strings are produced correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sprintf` and avoid the if-clause to add the leading zeroes:

```
fi[[i]] <- read.csv(file=sprintf("%03d.csv", i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be useful for you?

```
> paste0(sprintf("%03d",c(1,10,99,100,999,1000)), ".csv")
[1] "001.csv"  "010.csv"  "099.csv"  "100.csv"  "999.csv"  "1000.csv"
```

mpjdem's answer is better

```
> sprintf("%03d.csv",c(1,10,99,100,999,1000))
[1] "001.csv"  "010.csv"  "099.csv"  "100.csv"  "999.csv"  "1000.csv"
```